# Add Secure Boot Key to Live Distro

Tags: linux, kali-linux, liveusb, secure-boot

I wanted to ask if it was possible to load a key into my live persistence distro in order to get past Secure Boot without disabling? I imagine the answer is probably no, but I felt like asking anyhow.

Comment: I do this all the time on Ubuntu by creating my own private keys, in particular for the VMware drivers, which are compiled at run-time, and the third-party drivers for my Broadcom WiFi interface.

Comment: What resource do you use?

Comment: I'll need to submit an answer: there's too much information for comments.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said what you want the key for, but on Ubuntu I do this periodically to sign drivers manually. My BroadCom WiFi driver is third-party and unsigned, and I use the following script every time a new kernel is installed:-

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(whoami)" != "root" ]
then echo "wlsign: must be called from 'root'"
elif [ -z "$1" -o "$1" == "-c" ]
then
     [ "$1" == "-c" ] && \
     openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout wl.priv -outform DER -out wl.der -nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=BroadCom/"
     /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./wl.priv ./wl.der $(modinfo -n wl)
     [ "$1" == "-c" ] && mokutil --import wl.der
     [ "$1" == "-c" ] && echo Now reboot and select MOK install || modprobe wl
else
     [ "$1" != "-h" ] && echo "wlsign: invalid options - $@"
     echo 'wlsign [-c|-h] : signs proprietary Wireless kernel drivers'
     echo '            -c : create new keys (default: use existing)'
     echo '            -h : give this help information'
fi
```

I needed the `-c` option only once in order to create the key files initially. After using `-c` the system needs to be rebooted and the new key accepted into the UEFI firmware.

I have similar scripts for other unsigned drivers, especially the VMware drivers, which are compiled on the fly, so cannot ever be signed.

Since Kali and Ubuntu are both Debian derivatives, I hope the system directory structures are similar. Note that the `sign-file` program is installed into the kernel headers, so `linux-headers-*` will need to be installed for your kernel. There is a `kmodsign` program in `/usr/bin/`, which may be an alternative, but I haven't tried it.

I can't remember where I found this information, so I can't acknowledge its source.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I’m wanting to make my “Swiss Army Knife” Kali Linux persistence drive to be used wherever it’s needed - however, secure boot has gotten in the way in the past and old BIOS computers won’t read a bootable system from my flash stick either. I’ll definitely give your script a try - given this is a pretty new persistence system, I really have nothing to lose.

Comment: So I got the following error: "Failed to enroll new keys" both when running mokutil --import MOK.der with and without --root-pw. Anything to say about that? It seems articles online point to the machine needing to already be in Secure Boot mode, but I'm not able to boot this Live distro without switching it off in the first place.

Comment: Since `mokutil` adds data to the UEFI boot code, it makes sense that you should be booting in UEFI mode, since secure boot is not available in legacy mode. Why are you using live boot? This requirement is usually for an installed system; otherwise, where do you save the key files? If you create the live disc correctly, you should be able to boot in UEFI mode, which is what you need for secure boot.

Comment: AFH, I’m saying that I’m booting in UEFI mode but with Secure Boot disabled. I have to in order to install the keys on my live persistence OS. This is a persistence system, so I would imagine I could update the keys... unless that’s not allowed on live distros even with persistence...

Comment: Sorry, I have never used live persistence, so I don't know what's possible. As I see it, to use your boot disc on multiple systems, you will need either to create a USB which will run with secure boot (see `sbsign`), in which case you'll need to import any keys you create into each machine, or to live with disabling secure boot. Although about ArchLinux, [this article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Secure_Boot#PreLoader) gives a reasoable idea of what's involved.